# SwiftUI 2: the way to open view in new window

Tags: swift, macos, navigation, swiftui, scene

Lets imagine that I have an App

```
var storeVM = BookStoreViewModel(bla1: bla1, bla2: bla2, bla3: bla3)

@SceneBuilder var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        BookStoreView( model: storeVM )
    }
    
    #if os(macOS)
    Settings {
        SettingsView(model: config)
    }   
    #endif
}
```

BookStore have a Grid with a lot of books saved in some DB.

BookView can be initiated by a following way:

```
BookView(model: bookViewModel)
```

Target: to open BookView IN A NEW SEPARATED WINDOW(as example by click on the button). How can I do this?

---

Bonus question:
How can I open `SettingsView(model: config)` from the code?

---

PS: `NavigationLink` is not solution for me because I not using the `NavigationView`.

Answer (score 7):

#### Update: Xcode 14 / macOS 13

Now we can explicitly open needed window giving it identifier and use it in `openWindow` environment action.

```
class BookViewModel: ObservableObject {} 

class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedBook: BookViewModel?
}

@main
struct SwiftUI2_MacApp: App {
    @StateObject var appState = AppState()

    @SceneBuilder 
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {         // main scene
            ContentView()
              .environmentObject(appState)   // inject to update
                                             // selected book
        }

        Window("Book Viewer", id: "book") { // << here !!
            BookView(model: appState.selectedBook)
        }

        // also possible variant with injected model for group
        // WindowGroup("Book Viewer", id: "book", for: Book.self) {  book in // << here !!
        //   BookView(model: book)
        // }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState

    @Environment(\.openWindow) private var openWindow   // << !!

    var body: some View {

        // assuming selection in grid somewhere here to
        // appState.selectedBook

        Button("Open Book") {
            openWindow(value: "book")       // << here !!

        // for group variant with injected value
        // if let book = self.selectedBook {
        //    openWindow(value: "book", book)       // << here !!
        // }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: its impossible to have if( ) directly inside of WindowGroup(), need to wrap into another view; It's impossible to open init view from nullable model - I'm in any case need to return view, but returning empty view is a bad idea -I will got an empty window as result. Returning nil - will throw an error; it's looks like a hacky way to do with a following way ( I mean those injection ). But thanks for a try

Comment: @Andrew, is that run-time error, because it is compilable at my side?

Comment: No, compile errors; But in any case this is not really good solution, as truly even if it will work... Really easier and cleaner code will be in case of using AppKit... Is there are really no nicer way to open brand new window in swiftUI ?

Comment: This compiled fine for me, but I don't get any second window popping up. (I'm using Big Sur beta, Xcode 12.2 beta)

Comment: @RobN Facing same issue on 12.4 release + Big Sur 11.1

Answer (score 5):

I found this answer, which worked for me in terms of being able to open a new window: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651592?answerId=651132022#651132022

I'm on `xcode 12.3`, `Swift 5.3`, running Big Sur.

The following is an example of how to set things up so a button in the `ContentView` can be used to open the `OtherView` window.

```swift
@main
struct testApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        WindowGroup("OtherView") {
            OtherView()
        }
        .handlesExternalEvents(matching: Set(arrayLiteral: "*"))
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.openURL) var openURL

    var body: some View {
       Button("Other View") {
           if let url = URL(string: "test://otherview") {
               openURL(url)
           }
       }
    }
}

struct OtherView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Other View!")
    }
}
```

**Note:** Make sure to follow the URL Scheme instructions included in the linked answer (quoted here for convenience):

> Now in Project->Info->URL Types type in `test` in the URL Schemes field (and the identifier field too) to register our app with the system.

I achieved this by editing the `Info.plist` file and making the additions there, i.e `URL types` -> `URL Schemes`...:

[image: Info.plist]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will check this later

Comment: First of all - this is interesting solution and thanks for it. But Looks like its usless untill we have no ability to send viewModel into the window. Do you have any idea how to use it with viewModel?

Answer (score 4):

I have played with code from **hillmark**'s answer and got some better results than his code.

Even if this code is still not the answer, this may be useful for someone.

_

Generlly this code will be useless for you in case you need to work with View based on ViewModel.

**But if you need to work with View only - this is a good solution.**

```
@main
struct TestAppApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView()
        }
        // magic here
        .handlesExternalEvents(matching: Set(arrayLiteral: Wnd.mainView.rawValue))
        
        WindowGroup {
            HelperView()
        }
        // magic here
        .handlesExternalEvents(matching: Set(arrayLiteral: Wnd.helperView.rawValue))
    }
}

extension TestAppApp {
    struct MainView: View {
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Button("Open Main View") {
                    // magic here
                    Wnd.mainView.open()
                }
                
                Button("Open Other View") {        
                    // magic here
                    Wnd.helperView.open()
                }
            }
            .padding(150)
        }
    }

    struct HelperView: View {
        var body: some View {
            HStack {
                Text("This is ") + Text("Helper View!").bold()
            }
            .padding(150)
        }
    }
}



// magic here
enum Wnd: String, CaseIterable {
    case mainView   = "MainView"
    case helperView = "OtherView"
    
    func open(){
        if let url = URL(string: "taotao://\(self.rawValue)") {
            print("opening \(self.rawValue)")
            NSWorkspace.shared.open(url)
        }
    }
}
```

To work with this code you need to have the following:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you already try to use deep links to pass the "detail information"? E.g. the book identifier as in `taotao://MainView/ShowBook/BlaBla`. Try handling the deep link using `.onOpenUrl(...)` in the MainVIew.

Comment: No, I didn't. I'm using another system in my app than this. As this is still not enough flexible for me.

Comment: Detail information can be send too as long as it's a valid url. But be careful, using that link in safari will open your app. So don't trust any input you get.

Comment: How exactly would I pass detail information to the Helper View? Like, do I have access to the full Link somehow?

Comment: Answering my own question for completion's sake: Just appending a `.onOpenURL` on the Helper View does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into a similar problem in swiftui where I wanted to create a new desktop-level window, and I think finally found the solution.

```swift
Button("Show Bookmark") {
    // create a new NSPanel
    let window = NSPanel(contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500), styleMask: [.fullSizeContentView, .closable, .resizable, .titled], backing: .buffered, defer: false)
    
    // the styleMask can contails more, like borderless, hudWindow...
                    
    window.center()

    // put your swiftui view here in rootview
    window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: BookmarkView())
    window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)

    // if you want to close the window after delay
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()) {
        window.close()
    }
}
```

Comment: is it have all of SwiftUI features? Like windows grouping/ tabs/ etc?

Comment: yeah. I think so, but I didn't try this yet, maybe you should try it yourself. My intention at that time was to create a borderless window, like the one [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72299845/12741063).

Comment: I believe it is not, because here is no information for SwiftUI how to group windows :) This is hack, but not native solution for SwiftUI.  My solution is also hack, but it will work with SwiftUI windows features.

Comment: I'm really new at this.  I'd like to remove the references to the bookstore and just display an array of String in a list, like a pop-up, in the window.  Can this be done?