# How to validate a deep link when opening a new window in SwiftUI on macOS?

Tags: macos, swiftui, deep-linking

**TLDR:** How to distinguish between a link that the app sends internally and a link that originates from outside of the app?

**Details:**

If a SwiftUI app has multiple windows (scenes), a window can be opened programmatically via a deep link as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62915324/swiftui-2-the-way-to-open-view-in-new-window/65415593#65415593).

Contextual data can be included in the link. For example a book id in a library app.

```
fancyLibraryApp:viewer/book/42
```

Add the following modifier to your view to process this url and to view a book.

```
var body: some Scene
{
    Text("Title of \(book)").onOpenURL 
    {
        self.id = $0.description.lastPathComponent //parse the url as appropriate 
    }
}
```

Book is a value or object that you retrieve from the id passed through the url.
The id should be a binding so that the view gets updated.

A link can be send from elsewhere within your app **but** it can also be send from an **external source** such as safari or the Terminal app (`open fancyLibraryApp:viewer/book/42`).

Therefore the url **must be validated**. Is the user allowed to read this book or not? Is the user logged in or not?

Apple explains how to validate an incoming url [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/defining-a-custom-url-scheme-for-your-app), but only for iOS.

NSApplicationDelegate has a [function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplicationdelegate/2887193-application) `application(_ application: NSApplication, open urls: [URL])`

However that function is called after the view modifier `onOpenURL`.

So how can the url be verified?