# SwiftUI: Open multiple windows on App start on macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui, windowgroup

I'm trying to open two windows on App startup. One to show on another screen and the second to control the first window on my screen. Unfortunately I cannot get it running. I just tried to add a second `WindowGroup`, but it always just launches my first `WindowGroup`. I just read that this is the normal behaviour, but what is the correct way to open up two different windows on App startup?

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup("Test") {
            Text("Hello test")
                .frame(width: 1000, height: 1000, alignment: .center
                )
        }
        
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .frame(minWidth: 800, minHeight: 1000)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself with help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65411994/8308982)

Instead of putting the `openURL` part into a Button, just add it to the `onAppear` call of the `ContentView`.