# SwiftUI: show a window on startup in document-based macOS app

Tags: macos, swiftui

I've got a document-based SwiftUI app and I'm trying to show a welcome window on startup (like the one in Xcode).

I've got:

```
        Window("Welcome", id: "welcome") {
            WelcomeView()
        }
        .windowStyle(.hiddenTitleBar)
        .windowResizability(.contentSize)
```

This looks good and appears in the appropriate place in the Window menu (not among the document windows). The problem is that I can't figure out how to get it to show on startup. Things I've tried:

- `@Environment(\.openWindow) var openWindow` and calling `openWindow` in the `App` init function. This results in an error about needing to call `openWindow` from within the SwiftUI lifecycle (makes sense because `body` hasn't even been called yet).
- Delaying the call to `openWindow` by putting it in a `Task` and sleeping for a bit. Nothing happens.
- Using `@Environment(\.scenePhase)` to trigger the call to `openWindow`. This happens only after a document window is created (too late).
- Using `WindowGroup` instead of `Window` and `handlesExternalEvents`. `WindowGroup` doesn't seem to be the right thing to use: File -> New becomes a submenu with both my normal document, and the Welcome window.
- [The technique here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028697/swiftui-open-multiple-windows-on-app-start-on-macos) I think won't work because with a document-based app, I don't have a `View` instantiated on startup, and thus can't use `onAppear`.

I can most likely accomplish this by dropping down to AppKit, using an AppDelegate, explicitly creating a NSWindow and hosting the `WelcomeView` inside it. But I *really shouldn't have to do that*. Is there a way to do this in pure SwiftUI?

Update: I did accomplish this by dropping down to AppKit. Will leave this question here in case a nicer way becomes available.

Comment: Could you share how you did this in AppKit?